# Why is there no current flow in the wire?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance

[image]

Why is there no current flow between point $a$ and the junction next to the $4\;\mathrm{V}$ battery if there is a potential difference of $4\;\mathrm{V}$ between the points?

Comment: You need a closed circuit for a current to flow. Current can only flow from the battery's + terminal if the current can somehow get to the - side. The battery is not connected at the - side, so there is no way for any current to complete the circuit from + to -. There would be a current if there were some connection between a and b.

Comment: @hdhondt that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal power source no positive charge moves through it *from plus to minus*. The battery will only transport it from minus to plus through it's interior. The *only* way for positive charge to reach the minus terminal is to move through the circuit - if there is no circuit leading there, it wouldn't reach it.

With that in mind, the right part of the wire from the 4V source to point $a$ is isolated. In other words, it is an open circuit.

Consider these steps of thinking:

- In the beginning before switching on, electrons are evenly distributed in the wire piece.
- After switch-on, you suddenly have less positive charge at the minus-terminal. Positive charge in the wire piece moves towards that terminal - it is attracted - while equivalently electrons move away from it towards the other end of the wire piece, the point $a$.
- The electrons stop at $a$.
- Many charges move, so soon there are *many* electrons accumulating at point $a$. And it continues...
- At some point there are so many electrons accumulated that their combined electric field counteracts the repulsion of electrons from the minus-terminal. Then there is no net-push on them anymore, and all charge stops moving. In other words, no current.

This little line of thought happens very, very quickly. Current flows but gradually decreases in the very beginning, but very shortly after, it all stops again. Of this reason, there can be no **steady** current flowing in an open circuit. And the comment in the top of this answer told why this wire piece is considered an open circuit.

> Why is there no current flow between point $a$ and the junction next to the $4\;\mathrm V$ battery if there is a potential difference of $4\;\mathrm V$ between the points?

There is a potential difference across the battery yes, but there is none the minus-terminal and point $a$. After the situation described above is stable, the potential is equal through the wire piece and there is no potential difference from one point to another on this wire.

Comment: But surely there _is_ a potential difference of 4 volts between the terminals of the battery. What did you mean?

Comment: @Pieter Yes, there is a potential difference (voltage) across the battery. But not across the minus-terminal and point $a$, which is written in the question. I have updated the answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no closed circuit (loop) including point $a$.

Current is a continuous flow of charge. If some charge flows through the 4V cell to point $a$ there is nowhere for it to go to next.